# Java : GUI need help to make correct Condition

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, conditional-statements

i want to make line to look like that pic below,  i tried many time and this is the current code but it gives me a different looks so is there's anything missing in my condition

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int x = 10; x > 1; x--) {
                g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth() / i, getHeight() / x);
                g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth() / x, getHeight() / i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        MainClass panel = new MainClass();
        myFrame.add(panel);
        myFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        myFrame.setLocation(100, 100);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

here's the pic of my code & the wanted shape :

[image]

Comment: This is more a math question than a Java question, other than that break; looking suspicious as it is turning the inner for loop into a run one time only non-loop.

Comment: Looks like a geometry question really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use variables for paint distance between lines and only one for

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);          
       //variable of the begin of point
        int pointIni=0;
        //variable for the distance between lines
        int distance=20;
        //variable for the space between lines
        int cntLines=20;
        for (int i = 0; i < cntLines; i++) 
        {
           g.drawLine(0, 0, pointIni, getHeight()-pointIni);         
           pointIni=pointIni+distance;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        MainClass panel = new MainClass();
        myFrame.add(panel);
        myFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        myFrame.setLocation(100, 100);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: its works perfectly but i can't understand your code concept can u explain it to a little bit plus i had remove this two lines
 //variable for the space between lines
        int cntLines=20;
 and replaced (cntLines with ditance ) and it gives me the same output

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a nested loop for this. In the "expected" image, x and y are dependent on each other. As x grows, y shrinks. Try it with one loop only.

Comment: Thank u so much you were so helpful for me , i want to give you helpful point but i`m new here so i can't :'(, but really thank you